# Subquery using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I am using LINQ to SQL in my C# tutorial project but I have basic knowledge of it.

I made a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT ID,HeroName,HeroRarity,Initiative,Attack,Attack1 
FROM   CharactersName
WHERE  ID IN(
             SELECT HeroID 
             FROM   Hero_Group 
             WHERE GroupID=1
            )
```

(Hero_Group) is a table to deal with a many-to-many relation between (CharactersName) table and another table named (Groups) where a character can be in more than one group.

I tried to write it in LINQ like this:

```
void FilterGroup()
    {
        HDAEntities db = new HDAEntities();
        var query = from obj in db.CharactersNames
                    where obj.ID == from obj2 in db.Hero_Group
                                    where obj2.GroupID == comboBox1.SelectedIndex
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        obj2.GroupID
                                    }
                    select new
                    {
                        obj.ID,
                        obj.HeroName,
                        obj.HeroRarity,
                        obj.Initiative,
                        obj.Attack,
                        obj.Attack1
                    };
    }
```

But of course this is gibberish.

---

Can someone help me, please ? (be informed that I have little knowledge of LINQ to SQL)

~TIA~

Comment: What error are you getting? Try to revert inner query like this `where (from obj2 ... ).Contains(obj.ID)`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
void FilterGroup()
{
    HDAEntities db = new HDAEntities();

    var subQuery = db.Hero_Group.Where(h => h.GroupID == comboBox1.selectedIndex)
                                .Select(h => h.GroupID);

    var query = from obj in db.CharactersNames
                where subQuery.Contains(obj.ID)
                select new
                {
                    obj.ID,
                    obj.HeroName,
                    obj.HeroRarity,
                    obj.Initiative,
                    obj.Attack,
                    obj.Attack1
                };

    var result = query.ToList(); // this is where your query and subquery are evaluated and sent to the database

    db.Dispose();
    db = null;
}
```

Note that the subQuery is not evaluated until you call ToList(). You also need to dispose the object (or try the using statement to create the HDAEntities object). Also, make sure you don't dispose the db before evaluating the query (calling ToList after Dispose will throw an exception).

Comment: I am getting error at this line==>    where subQuery.Contains(obj.ID)

Comment: Error 3 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HDA_InfoBook\HDA_InfoBook\ViewAll.cs 104 25 HDA_InfoBook

Comment: Are your obj.ID and h.GroupID of the same type ? Or maybe obj.ID is string ?

Comment: Table (Hero_Group): HeroID(smallint),GroupID(tinyint)  
- Table (CharactersName): ID(smallint) 
- Table (Groups): ID(tinyint)

Comment: @Cosmin you can `using` statement to dispose the dbcontext

Comment: yes, that would be the way to do it right. The sample is adapted to the sample provided by the one who asked the questions, but if you are using the DbContext directly (not enclosed by repository/unit of work patterns), the using statement would be the right thing to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var query = from obj in db.CharactersNames
                where (from obj2 in db.Hero_Group
                       where obj2.GroupID == comboBox1.SelectedIndex
                       select new {obj2.GroupID}).Contains(obj.ID)
                select new
                {
                    obj.ID,
                    obj.HeroName,
                    obj.HeroRarity,
                    obj.Initiative,
                    obj.Attack,
                    obj.Attack1
                };
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var query = from obj in db.CharactersNames
                where (from obj2 in db.Hero_Group 
                       where obj2.GroupID == comboBox1.SelectedIndex
                       select new {obj2.GroupID}).Contains(obj.ID)
                select new
                {
                    obj.ID,
                    obj.HeroName,
                    obj.HeroRarity,
                    obj.Initiative,
                    obj.Attack,
                    obj.Attack1
                };
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please elaborate your answer and use the code formatting.